# Absolute path in ProcessBuilder is correct, how to use relative path to instead?

Tags: java, path, relative-path

The following code can be run, but now I want to use a relative path:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar","E:\\IntelijWorkspace\\probactrScheduler\\Container\\probactrContainer.jar","E:\\albianjJars3.0", "E:\\albianjJars3.0\\config");
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you're trying to achieve, what you tried, .... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which path it should be relative to. If you want the path of the running jar (e.g. run with "java -jar myjar.jar"), then you can get the path like this (from the current class "MyClass" you're in):

```
String path = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

And then prepend that path to your relative path.